# Billboard design for 10ft width * 5 ft height size ... what is actual down scaling size in illustrator to prevent system hang

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, print-production, billboard

to design 10ft * 5ft  banner of actual size  what is the exact process for down scaling illustrator and raster images in photoshop  please guide me i am new

Comment: Thre is nothing resource wise that you gain from designing in scale. Other than circumventing the size limitation in illustrator but even this is being lifted as we speak. The only beneficial thing is to work with proxies but thats a completely different ballgame

Comment: Welcome to GDSE!  Asking the printer what they recommend is the best way, but see some of the answers below.

Comment: If you could edit your question with some context as far as where the banner will be used, substrate you are printing on, printing method, anything else that you have, it would help us to give you an accurate answer for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It greatly depends on the end use of the banner, the printer it is being printed on, the substrate, and the company you are working with.

The newer printers (in the last 10ish years) can print 1200 x 1200 DPI, some of them even higher at good quality and color.  If it's a sports field sponsor banner, doesn't really matter.  If it's a trade show banner that could be looked at from a foot or 2 away, the higher the quality the better.

10' x 5' is not too large even for older versions of illustrator.  That is a standard flat bed printer size.  Since boards like that aren't usually seen from that far away (not like a billboard), I wouldn't scale it down at all.

But if you must, I would only go down 1:2 at the smallest, and still size your photos to at least 300 DPI.  If you do scale it, make sure you communicate with your sign company on what your final size is, and what scale you are sending them to make sure that there are no miscommunications.

Comment: by the way viewing distance for this billboard is minimum 10 feet,                               
        suppose i will scale it down at 1:2  then starting new document with 300 ppi or less ?

Comment: I would go 300 or greater personally, but again, ask the printer who is producing the banner what they recommend.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check these things with the printing company first, but best guess is you can scale down the artwork to 1:5 or 1:10.

Comment: Note thay have made a change in newest illustrator so that it should not ne neccesery to design down in scale anyomre